# curl html file through mailchimp inlineCss API

Tags: api, curl, command-line-interface, html-email, mailchimp

I am using MailChimps inline-css form at: http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css. It does a great job of preparing an html file for use in sending as an email.

I have an api key. I prefer not to have to run their PHP app for only one API call. If it possible to use curl to access their inlineCss API? If so, what is the syntax?

Here is the doc page: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.2/inlinecss.func.php

See also line: 2096 of this gist: https://gist.github.com/740362

My key looks something like: 
    f1b46???????????????????f2d5-us2

Here is a start of what I will like to achieve:

```
curl post -d @input.html apiKey=xxxxxxxx "http://us1.api.mailchimp.com/1.2/"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I hacked up for anyone looking for a similar solution. Comments, other options are welcomed:

import os
    import re
    import urllib
    import mechanize
    import xml.sax.saxutils as saxutils
    from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape

```
try:  
  issueRoot = os.environ['newslettersroot'] + os.environ['currYear'] + '/' + os.environ['issueRoot'] + '/'
except KeyError: 
   print "Please run init.bat"
   sys.exit(1)

srcEmailFilename = 'email.html'
dstEmailFilename = 'email_inline_css.html'


# retrieve <body> section only
html = open(issueRoot + srcEmailFilename, 'rb').read()
html = re.findall("(?si)<body.*?</body>", html)[0]


# use mailchimp inlineCss site to inject class rules into html tags
response = mechanize.urlopen("http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css")
# retrieve form
form = mechanize.ParseResponse(response, backwards_compat=False)[0]

form["html"] = html
# form["strip"] = "checked"

# submit form and retrieve result
html = mechanize.urlopen(form.click()).read()


match = re.search('<textarea name="text" cols="100" rows="12">(.*?)</textarea>', html, re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)

if not match:
    print html
    exit("Expected to find output from mailchimp.")

# clean up output
html = match.group(1)
html = saxutils.unescape(html)
html = urllib.unquote_plus(html)
html = unescape(html, {"&apos;": "'", "&quot;": '"'})
html = html.replace('&amp;', '&').replace('%2F', '/').replace('%3A', ':')


# @sed -r 's/ class="[a-zA-Z0-9-]+"//g' %newslettersroot%%currYear%\%issueRoot%\email_inlinedcss.html > %newslettersroot%%currYear%\%issueRoot%\email_removedstyle.html

#replace class tags
html = re.sub(r'(?sim)\s*class="[a-zA-Z0-9-]+"', "", html)

fh = open(issueRoot + dstEmailFilename, 'wb')
fh.write(html)
fh.close()
```